# Parsing XML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, json, xml, elasticsearch

I'm trying to parse an XML file that is full of articles from a newspaper, save it in a JSON format, save it to a list, and later bulk index it with `elasticsearch`. From each article, I want to get the date it was published, the type of article (advertisement, normal article etc.) and its title and content. The problem I'm having with this, is that I'm having trouble separating the title of the article from its content.

An example of one of the articles is shown here:

```
<pm:KBroot xmlns:pm="http://www.politicalmashup.nl" recordfile="">
<pm:root>
<pm:docinfo/>
<pm:meta>
<dc:date xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">1923-03-01</dc:date>
<dc:subject xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">artikel</dc:subject>
<dc:identifier xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
>ddd:010563762:mpeg21:p001:a0005</dc:identifier>
<dc:source xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<dc:source>
<pm:link pm:source="832675288" pm:description="De Telegraaf"/>
</dc:source>
</dc:source>
</pm:meta>
<pm:content pm:source="http://kranten.kb.nl/view/article/id/ddd:010563762:mpeg21:p001:a0005"
pm:id="ddd:010563762:mpeg21:p001:a0005">
<title pm:id="ddd:010563762:mpeg21:p001:a0005.t">De jongste maaregelen op den Rechter-
Rijn-oeven.</title>
<text>
<p pm:id="ddd:010563762:mpeg21:p001:a0005.1">â–  volgende redenen rijn bezet: lo. ter vereenvcudi-f
ging ran het douane-wezen en 2o. wegens fit' demonstratieÂ» en vergaderingen, welke in deÂ»e gebieden
zijn gehouden en gericht waren tegen de bezettingstroepen en de bezettingsautoriteiten. De
rijkscommissaris voor de bezette genie den heeft geweigerd, deze kennisgevins door te zenden. â€”
(Wolft},</p>
</text>
</pm:content>
</pm:root>
</pm:KBroot>
```

From this, I want to get the date from the `dc:date` tag, the subject from th `dc:subject` tag, the title from the `title` tag and the text from the `text` tag, for each article in the tag `pm:KBroot`. What I have so far is the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("telegraaf-1923.xml", "r"), "xml")

all_articles = []

for article in soup.find_all("root"):
    new_article = {
        "date": article.date.string,
        "subject": article.subject.string,
        "title": article.content.title.string,
        "body": article.content.text
    }

    all_articles.append(new_article)
```

which results in the following for the above article:

```
{
    "date": "1923-03-01",
    "body": "De jongste maaregelen op den Rechter- Rijn-oeven.\u25a0 volgende redenen rijn bezet: lo. ter vereenvcudi-f ging ran het douane-wezen en 2o. wegens fit' demonstratie\u00bb en vergaderingen, welke in de\u00bbe gebieden zijn gehouden en gericht waren tegen de bezettingstroepen en de bezettingsautoriteiten. De rijkscommissaris voor de bezette genie den heeft geweigerd, deze kennisgevins door te zenden. \u2014 (Wolft},",
    "title": "De jongste maaregelen op den Rechter- Rijn-oeven.",
    "subject": "artikel"
}
```

As you can see, the problem is separating the title and the body of the article, since they both have `text` tags, and so `body` contains both the title and the body of the article. I tried using `"body": article.content.text.p`, but that gives `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'p'`.

Comment: `text` has special meaning in BS. it is like function  `get_text()` or `string` in you code - so maybe try `article.content.p.string` or you have to use `find('text')`

Answer (score 1):

`text` has special meaning in BS. It is like `string` in you code (or function `get_text()`)

So `article.content.text` means `article.content.string` or `article.content.get_text()`

But you can use

```
article.content.p.string
```

or you have to use `find('text')`

```
article.content.find('text').p.string
```

Comment: I already figured out another way to do it, but now I'm struggling how to get the `pm:source` content, so if you could help with that I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: this works for me `article.content.attrs['pm:source']` or even `article.content['pm:source']`